# How to set timer based on 2 period of hours?

Tags: c#, datetime, timer, visual-studio-2019

I have a single function that needs to run on 2 separate time period. 8AM-12AM Period1, 12AM-8AM Period2.

I have 1 Timer at the moment that runs 24/7 for every 1 hour.

How do i split this timer into 2 separate time period?

I have a pre-written code but i believe this is not an efficient method so i would like to ask community if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Below is my code example

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 8 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
{
    LogMessageToFile("Running Peak Period - Period 1");
    LogMessageToFile("Check will now do every 1 count");
    //Code here
    --SomeCodes--
}
else if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 0 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
{
    LogMessageToFile("Running Night Period - Period 2");
    LogMessageToFile("Check will now do every 3 count");
    //Code here
    --SomeCodes--
}
```

I see that my code then will only run once when it reach 8am and 12am.
Result should be that it runs the entire period.

I.e. 8 am until 12 midnight, then 12 midnight until 8 am.

Comment: Can you please explain far more clearly what "run on 2 separate time period" means?

Comment: it meant that i will need to run 2 different code within 1 timer function. The timer runs 24/7 and executes code every 1 hour. However i will need to have it run different codes on different time period. however i might already been answered down below and im running a test for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to try 'more-less' comparison instead of equal-comparison. Eg.

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 12) // this means condition that current time is between 8 and 12 hours
{
  //Period #1
}
else
{
  //Period #2
}
```

upd: misread your question. If you would like the code to be executed between 8 AM and 12 **PM** then you should make a condition based on a 24h time format, eg:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 0 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 8)
{
  //Night time
}
else
{
  //Peak time
}
```

Comment: Hi kleshenki , no , you didnt misread. It is 8am to 12am. as midnight is AM , midday is PM.

Comment: your second code example i believe will be the most efficient as anything after 0 ( 0 is 12 midnight i assume ) , and before 8 ( 8am i assume ) , will run the night time code , else all will run peak time code.

Comment: yeah, that' true

Comment: accepted your 2nd code as the answer. thank you @kleshenki

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Set the Timer interval to 60 mins and put the following code in the Timer Tick event handler.

```
int hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
if ((hour > 8 && hour <= 23) || hour == 0) Console.WriteLine ("Work time");
if (hour > 0 && hour <= 8) Console.WriteLine ("Sleep time");
```